# Spring MVC and Tomcat: redirect to error page on JSP exception

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm forcing an `org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException` in one of my JSP-s by misspelling a property name and trying to show my error page for this with no luck. I know that the `@ControllerAdvice/@ExceptionHandler` solution works for controller exceptions only, but answers here on SO suggest that the web.xml configuration way should work.

I have a WEB-INF/views/error.jsp with `<%@page isErrorPage="true"%>` and this in `web.xml`:

```
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/views/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>   
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/WEB-INF/views/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

I get only an exception in the log and a half-rendered view. I have also tried adding an error controller and change `<location>` to `/error`. Same result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working after several restarts, I think I didn't change anything. Getting the exception was a bit tricky but I found the answer in another question.

```
<c:if test="${empty exception }">
    <c:set var="exception" value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.exception']}"/>
</c:if>
```

With this I can handle both controller and JSP exceptions on the same page.